Using Chebyshev inequality, determine the minimum number of coin tosses such that tails appear 450-550 times with probability 0.97
Using Chebyshev inequality, determine the minimum number of coin tosses such that, with a minimum probability of 0.97, the number of tails occurrence is between 450 and 550.
I am quite stuck on this problem. What I tried is to let $X$ be the random variable that tracks the number of times tails appear on a toss out of $n$ throws, which means that $n \ge 450$. Thus, $X$ is a binomial random variable, where $p_k = \binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{2^k}\frac{1}{2^{n-k}}=\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{2^n}, k \in\{0,1,\dots,n\}$, considering the coin in fair. The mean of $X$ is $M(X) = n\cdot\frac{1}{2}$, and $var(X)=\frac{n}{4}$.
Then, I recognize that, starting from $P(450\le X \le 550) \ge 0.97$, I need to reach a statement that involves $P(|X-M(X)|\ge50)\le\frac{var(X)}{50^2}$, but I am not sure how. Important to note is that, in my course, the inequality was presented as $P(|X - M(X)|\ge \epsilon)\le \frac{var(X)}{\epsilon^2}, \forall \epsilon>0$, where I guessed that in my problem $\epsilon$ is 50 because $450\le x \le 550 \iff -50 \le x - 500 \le 50\iff |x - 500|\le 50$. But, of course, for this to be the case, then $M(X) = 500$ which I cannot say so simply, because then $n=1000$ and does not even involve the $0.97$ probability.
Any help is much appreciated!

Not seeing this as a Chebyshev problem, though maybe I am missing something.  Chebyshev is pretty crude really...it works for "all"  distributions after all.  Brute force is easy enough here (on a machine), or you could use the normal approximation to the binomial.

I don't doubt what you said is right, however the professor specifically asked us to attempt to use the Chebyshev inequality for this one. If there is any practical reason to this, it eludes me...

Yeah, I don't see it.  You won't come close to the true answer.  But of course you can try.  Guess a number of tosses, $N$, like $1000$.  Then $\sigma=15.89$  and you can apply your inequality.  Easy to check that it fails to confirm that $N=1000$ suffices (though, in truth, it does).  So then try a different guess.  No reason to imagine that you'll even find a workable number this way, though I believe you do.

Just for reference:  doing it by brute force gives $N=958$ as the desired minimum (barring implementation error, of course).

Perhaps the point of the exercise is to confirm that Chebyshev is a poor tool for questions like these.  Really not what it is good for.
